# 'rake native' fails with "undefined method split for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm creating a Ruby C extension for which I would like to create prepackaged binary packages, as the compilation requires a fair amount of dependencies.  I'm new to Ruby, but it seems like `gem` doesn't want to create platform-specific packages, so the common way is to use the rake-compiler gem, and do `rake native`.  I can get it to compile the extension, but then it fails with the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

Running with --trace shows that the error is in rake-compiler-1.0.7/lib/rake/extensiontask.rb:515:

```
def ruby_api_version(ruby_version)
  ruby_version.split(".")[0, 2].join(".")
end
```

This is because ruby_version is nil.  It is called from rake-compiler-1.0.7/lib/rake/extensiontask.rb:262 in define_native_tasks():

```
ruby_versions = @ruby_versions_per_platform[platf] || []
sorted_ruby_versions = ruby_versions.sort_by do |ruby_version|
    ruby_version.split(".").collect(&:to_i)
end
spec.required_ruby_version = [
    ">= #{ruby_api_version(sorted_ruby_versions.first)}",
    "< #{ruby_api_version(sorted_ruby_versions.last).succ}.dev"
]
```

`@ruby_versions_per_platform` is set to `{}` in the constructor, but no line of code ever sets it.  Thus, `sorted_ruby_versions` is empty, and `.first` and `.last` are nil, which results in the argument to `ruby_api_version` being nil.

Looking at git blame in the project shows that the these lines are 2 years old, and a result of the changeset https://github.com/rake-compiler/rake-compiler/commit/0dc23504cb03ed2fb3c506e1bb58af48d3851d1e.  However, `ruby_versions_per_platform` is never assigned to outside the constructor, which means `ruby_api_version` will always get called with nil and will always fail.  So how can this have worked for two years?

And more importantly, what do I have to do to get `rake native` to actually work?

I am using macOS 10.12.6, Ruby 2.3.7p456 installed with MacPorts (selected with `port select --set ruby ruby26`), rake-compiler 1.0.7, and rake-12.3.2.

Rakefile:

```
require "rake/extensiontask"

gemspec = Gem::Specification::load("mygem.gemspec")

Gem::PackageTask.new(gemspec) do |pkg|
end

Rake::ExtensionTask.new("mygem", gemspec) do |ext|
end
```

mygem.gemspec

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = "mygem"
  s.version = "1.0.0rc1"
  s.authors = [ "John Doe" ]
  s.summary = "Awesome library"
  s.description = "Awesome library because, reasons"
  s.licenses = [ 'MIT' ]
  s.email = "johndoe@null.com"
  s.homepage = "http://www.null.com"
  s.extensions = %w[ext/mygem/extconf.rb]
  s.files = FileList['lib/**/*.rb', 'ext/**/*.{rb,c,h}']
  s.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.required_ruby_version = '>= 1.8'
end
```

My project layout is

```
Rakefile
mygem.gemspec
ext/
    mygem/
        extconf.rb
        mygem.c      (generated with SWIG 3.0)
lib/
    mygem.rb
```

Comment: Sounds like a known issue https://github.com/rake-compiler/rake-compiler/issues/156